# Find and delete duplicate txt files

Tags: bash, files, text-processing, scripting

I have a folder with around 300 text files, is there any command that reads every every file indivdually and deletes the duplicate files? I mean the content and not the file names.

Comment: I would start with `md5sum *` and then count how many files have the same checksum.

Comment: Needless to say: back up your folder before trying any of the solutions suggested here.

Comment: Yeah, i always do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `fdupes`, it can list all the duplicated files in your folder.

You could refer to [this](http://bitflop.com/tutorials/finding-and-removing-dublicate-files-with-fdupes.html) online tutorial on how to use the `fdupes` command.

**Testing**

I created 3 files named *file1*, *file2* and *file3* with *file1* and *file2* having exactly similar contents.

Now, I executed my command as,

```
fdupes -rdN .
```

Where (quoting from the above refered link),

1. The `r` option makes fdupes search for files recursively.
2. The `d` option makes fdupes delete duplicates.
3. The `N` option, when used together with `d`, preserve the first file
   in each set of duplicates and delete the others without prompting
   the user.

After executing the above command, I have *file1* and *file3* in my folder and *file2* got deleted.

Comment: Hmm, i will try the command i got it via homebrew.

Comment: @DisplayName, do you want to keep the filenames?

Comment: What does the `.` do?

Comment: @DisplayName, `.` is used for the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Pierre-Olivier Vares's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165065/80216) needs to have `-print0` and `xargs -0`
to work with filenames with spaces, etc.

Like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |
    xargs -0 md5sum |
    awk '{print $2,$1}' |
    sort -k 2 |
    uniq --all-repeated=prepend -f 1 |
    awk '/^$/ { I=1 }; /^./ { if (I==0) {print $1} I = 0; }' |
    xargs echo
```

Run this.  If it produces reasonable results,
run it again with `xargs rm --` instead of `xargs echo`.

Comment: It’s a valid comment that [Pierre-Olivier Vares’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165065/80216) won’t work with filenames with spaces.  But this doesn’t fix it; `print $2` and `print $1` will blow up for filenames with spaces or tabs, and it’s just about impossible to preserve filenames with newlines when you’re processing them with Awk.

Answer (score 0):

If fdupes isn't available, you could also use:

```
for first in *.txt
do
    for second in *.txt
    do
        if  diff $first $second >/dev/null 2>&1 && [ "$first" != "$second" ]
        then
            #echo $first and $second match. Deleting ${second}. # Optional, uncomment to use.
            rm $second
        fi
    done
done
```

Note: This is very inefficient. It will execute diff 90,000 times for 300 files. It'll still be very quick if they're fairly small files, but could take a long time if they're big files.

Answer (score 0):

As a secondary answer, when fdupes is not available, a more efficient way would use md5 to get the hash, and sort and uniq to find duplicates without a double shell loop

Something like : (put all on one line, without comments)

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt'   // get recursively all .txt files
| xargs md5sum         // compute the md5 sum
| awk '{print $2,$1}'  // reverse the md5sum output
| sort -k 2            // sorts on the md5 hash
| uniq --all-repeated=prepend -f 1     // get groups of duplicate files
| awk '/^$/ { I=1 }; /^./ { if (I==0) {print $1} I = 0; }'  // see below
| xargs rm             // delete
```

would delete every .txt file already encountered

(Rigorously, I'm neglecting the case of MD5 collisions, as they shouldn't occur in normal situations.)

Explaining the uniq and awk lines :

```
Let's assume :
file1:This is a 1st content
file2:This is a 1st content
file3:This is a 2nd content
file4:This is a 3rd content
file5:This is a 1st content
file6:This is a 3rd content
```

Result of sort is :

```
file4 801620325e6bc5efa4333a9413811e23
file6 801620325e6bc5efa4333a9413811e23
file3 8f9722a09b4c6f0ddf867e268193ea1b
file1 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
file2 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
file5 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
```

`uniq --all-repeated=prepend -f 1` keeps only duplicates, prepending each block with a blank line :

```
(blank line)
file4 801620325e6bc5efa4333a9413811e23
file6 801620325e6bc5efa4333a9413811e23
(blank line)
file1 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
file2 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
file5 a066d80d23803dffa9fbc1cdcd95e163
```

Then, a mini awk script ignores the blank lines, and print only the first field of lines not following a blank line

```
(--> not printed: blank line)
(--> not printed: file4)
file6
(--> not printed: blank line)
(--> not printed: file1)
file2
file5
```

Then, a xargs rm can rm the remaining (that is, duplicates files)

Comment: Adding -type f to the find command, to ignore symbolic links and directories.